# How to mark an OData context as dirty?

Tags: c#, odata, uwp

I have a UWP application using the OData client. I have a `Customer` that has a collection of `Order`s. When I add an new order for this customer via the order data service, I need to reload this property for the customer object. I am issuing a `BeginLoadProperty` on that object for the `Orders` property, but nothing happens. I suspect this is because OData thinks the object has not changed. I'd like to either mark the customer object as dirty so OData will fetch all the properties again, or just force the `Orders` property to reload.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

var customerQuery = (DataServiceQuery<Customer>)Container.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == id);
var result = await customerQuery.ExecuteAsync();
var customer = result.ToList().customers.First();
Container.BeginLoadProperty(customer, "Phones", callback, object);

var newPhone = new Phone() { CustomerId = customer.Id };
Container.AddToPhones(newPhone);

var customerQuery = (DataServiceQuery<Customer>)Container.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == id);
var result = await customerQuery.ExecuteAsync();
var customer = result.ToList().customers.First();
Container.BeginLoadProperty(customer, "Phones", callback, object);
```

Comment: What do you meen by nothing happens? Did you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see the traffic to the server? Maybe a change to the [`MergeOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.mergeoption(v=vs.113).aspx) property of the DeviceContext changes the behaviour?

Comment: Could you please post some of your codes to let us know what are you currently trying?

Comment: Lots of code, let me post an example. Thanks.

Comment: With the snippet posted, I am trying to add a new phone number for an existing customer. When I first load the customer object and do the BeginLoadProperty it executes the callback and populates the phone collection. When I add the new phone number it saves in the DB fine, but the second BeginLoadProperty does not execute the callback. If I quit the app and restart, then the new phone number will be in the Phones collection for this customer.